# AspNet Web API Filering - Exclude from results

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Trying to determine how to exclude records from results in ASPNET Web API.  A PSQL example query would be:

```
select 
    *
from
    vwpurchaseorderlist
WHERE
    not status IN ('Closed','VOID','Deleted');
```

How would you implement a filter to handle this where a consumer of the api can apply their own status filter?

I have a parameter object which handles pagination parameters and also contains a string property called ExcludeStatus.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an "in" for a fixed property you could pass a list of those values and use them in, say, dapper.

Dapper supports passing an array of values for an in clause.

https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper#list-support

```
connection.Query<int>("select .... where Id in @Ids", new { Ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } });
```

You would if course also need some offset nn and fetch next mm ( or equivalent) for your paging.

On the other hand, if you want super flexible querying, you could use odata.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/first-odata-api